# Dockerfile FROM AS throws Invalid Reference Format

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, continuous-deployment

## I'm trying to use a multistep Dockerfile that uses FROM AS, but when I run the Dockerfile in a Jenkins job I get an error

```
FROM node:8.12.0-alpine AS firstStep
Error parsing reference: "node:8.12.0-alpine AS firstStep" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

The Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM node:8.12.0-alpine AS firstStep

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

# Copy both the package.json and the package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

COPY . .

# Deployment container
FROM nginx:1.14.0-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --update curl

#set env var for certs
ENV NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS /confs/MyPem.pem

# Forward logs to stdout and stderr
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

# Create nginx config dir and copy nginx files for environments into it
RUN mkdir /confs
COPY ./nginxconf/* /confs/

#This copies the Keystore from the workspace and places it at the root of the container
COPY ./MyPem.pem /confs/MyPem.pem

COPY --from=firstStep /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod a+x /opt/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: What version of Docker do you have locally?  I feel like I've seen one or two occasions where the local Docker is too old to actually support multi-stage builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you check in [dockerhub.com](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/?tab=tags&page=1&name=node%3A8.12.0-alpine) the image node:8.12.0-alpine indeed does not exists, Use for example "node:8.12-alpine" . Also you should use lowercase for "firstStep" so ... "firststep"

Answer (score 0):

Support for multi-stage builds was added in [17.05.0](https://github.com/moby/moby/releases/tag/v17.05.0-ce). You can check the current version of the docker client and server with `docker version`. You'll need to upgrade the docker engine performing the build. Older docker releases are not supported once a new major release is delivered, so you'll want to pick a current stable release. Follow the [installation guide from docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/) for your platform to install from the docker repos, you'll often find that Linux distributions have older versions of docker in their repos.